# Find the root of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers $z$ such that

$$z^2=12−16i,$$

and give your answer in the form $a+bi$.

We set

$$z= a+bi,$$

thus,

$$z^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + (2ab)i.$$

Equating both $z^2$ we have

$$ a^2 - b^2 = 12\text{ and }ab = -8.$$

I am told that I can find the answer by using the quadratic formula. However, I don't see a way how can I apply the quadratic formula with the given equation. quadratic formula works when we have

$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$

I don't know how do i apply this in the context of $z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the coolest (though not necessarily easiest) way to do with would be to use Euler's Identity. Set $12-16i=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$, solve for $\theta$ using the fact that $\sqrt{(12+16i)(12-16i)}\cos(\theta)=12$. Then use the fact that $\cos(\theta/2)+i\sin(\theta/2)=\sqrt{\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)}$ since $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $ab=-8$, we have $b=-8/a$ so in the equation
$$
a^2-b^2=12
$$
we can put $-8/a$ in place of $b$, getting
$$
a^2-\frac{64}{a^2} = 12,
$$
whence
$$
a^4 - 64 = 12a^2
$$
or
$$
c^2 - 64 = 12c.
$$
That's an ordinary quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the constant with $a^2+3ab/2-b^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

From $a^2-b^2=12$ and $ab=-8$ you can get
$$a^2-\frac{64}{a^2}=12.$$ 
This can be converted to 
$$a^4-12a^2-64=0.$$
Use $t=a^2$ to get
$$t^2-12t-64=0.$$
Now solve for $t$ (hence $a$ and $b$).

Answer (score 0):

From $ab = -8$ we have $b = -\frac{8}{a}$. Substituting into the other equation
$$ a^2 - \frac{8^2}{a^2} = 12 $$

Multiplying through by $a^2$
$$ a^4 - 12a^2 - 64 = 0 $$

You now have a quadratic equation in $a^2$